# Swift 4 / Xcode 9.2 - Audio Player

Tags: swift, avaudiosession

For playing back audio I went through a bigger post here. Resulting in the best version now, but:

```
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
```

does not work, giving a String member error on .playback. Here´s the full code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func triggerSample(_ sender: Any) {
    playSound()
}

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "soundName", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        /* The following line is required for the player to work on iOS 11. Change the file type accordingly*/
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

        /* iOS 10 and earlier require the following line:
         player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3) */

        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

---

UPDATE: The solution is written in the commented out sections above: Regarding this, use the following playSound()for Xcode 9.2:

```
func playSound() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MWSTW_Bowie", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } //end of do/catch

} // end of playSound()
```

Comment: device is silent/volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works just fine. Just make sure you have an MP3 in the App bundle named "soundName" of type `.mp3`

[image]

Comment: Great to see, getting the same error with correctly named mp3 again here...Donno. how to really import the mp3 to the project? Sometimes it is not added into the ressources, where to check?Might be an issue...

Comment: sure, Sorry:Type 'String' has no member 'playback'

Comment: Looking at my image from above, which line number?

Comment: line22: It refers to the .playback. I use Xcode 9.2

Comment: alright, use it for Tutorials. Possible to use old and new XCode parallel?

Comment: Yes you can install multiple versions of Xcode on the same machine.

Comment: THX so much, COSMO!! Going to update for the player app!!

Comment: @COSMOBAKER never/don't put code as Screenshot, use edit option and add actual code.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati the point of the screenshot was to show the inspector, with the mp3 file. Still not a good idea?